# Xamarin Cross Plateform Binding date and time from datePicker and TimePicker using MVVM architecture

Tags: c#, mvvm, datepicker

I need some help in my project and I hope get ansewrs. So I am trying to select time and date from date picker and time picker and binded in the ViewModel.
This is what I tried in the View:

Views:

```
<Picker x:Name="Type" TextColor="Black"     
      SelectedIndexChanged="Type_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

demande.xaml.cs :

```
private void Fin_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime datefin = Fin.Date;
    CongéViewModel.datF = datefin;
}
```

ViewModels:

```
public static DateTime datF;

public Command PostCommandCongé
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async() => 
        {
            var congésServices = new CongéServices();
            _selectedCongé.Type = typ;
            _selectedCongé.VAC_From = datD;
            _selectedCongé.VAC_To = datF;
            _selectedCongé.VAC_Demi = demiJ;
           await congésServices.PostCongéAsync(_selectedCongé);
        });
    }
}
```